# No way to delete IndexedDB under Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, privacy, indexeddb

How to delete IndexedDBs in Google Chrome? I've performed "Clear browsing data" and nothing happened. There is still bunch of IndexedDB from different domains... All other data has been removed.

In Developer Tools is no option to delete IndexedDB.

[image: Google Chrome Clear browsing data screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116372
You will have the option to clear indexedDB (and other client side storage options like: localstorage etc') soon...

Answer (score 2):

According to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=64050, IndexedDB directories don't get deleted if there are open connections to them.  Have you tried shutting down the browser, waiting until all processes are gone, and then using "clear browsing data"?

Answer (score 2):

If you were still accessing IndexedDB when trying to clear history then the database won't be deleted cause it's already in use. In that case you need to close the browser first and then try to clear history again.

Alternatively you can delete all IndexedDB databases manually from:

Windows `C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\IndexedDB`

Linux: `/home/{username}/.config/google-chrome/IndexedDB`

Comment: It has been very useful, I just looked up the equivalent folder in Ubuntu (/ home / {username} / .config / google-chrome / IndexedDB)